# Write character/line from a string in bash?

Tags: string, bash, character, line, cut

I want to get this string -> `Example example1`

in this form:

```
E  
x  
a  
m  
p  
l  
e

e  
x  
a  
m  
p  
l  
e  
1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fold utility` with `width=1`:

```
echo 'Example example1' | fold -w1
E
x
a
m
p
l
e

e
x
a
m
p
l
e
1
```

**Another option is `grep -o`:**

```
echo 'Example example1' | grep -o .
E
x
a
m
p
l
e

e
x
a
m
p
l
e
1
```

Comment: This is a perfect recipe for `fold`!

Comment: @user3061736: please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: Not really a bash solution, though, since you're calling external utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard unix tools, you can do, for example:

`echo "Example example1" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'`

Using pure bash:

`echo "Example example1" | while read -r -n 1 c ; do echo "$c"; done`